# count no of locations in my code any error please find out in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I want count the data base field rows.Here is my sample code .

**Controller:**

```
function thetotaluploads() {
    $this->load->model(' num _property');
    $row['no_of_uploads'] = $this->num_property->count_uploads();
    echo json_encode($row['no_of_uploads']);
    $this->load->view('secondpage', $row);
}

//This is my model
function count_uploads() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(location) as count FROM hotels");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row();
        return $row->count; // return the count
    }
    return 0; // if we get there We don't have anything.
}
```

**View :**

```
<div class = "rightside">
    <p><?php echo $_POST['location'];
?>: <?php echo $row['count']; ?> properties found</p>
</div>
```

**Error:**

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: row
>
> Filename: views/secondpage.php
>
> Line Number: 87

Comment: Maybe you want to explain in a bit more detail what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: try with echo  `$no_of_uploads` in view instead `$row['count']`

Comment: Just echo $no_of_uploads in view .

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the count as a variable of array with this statement:

```
$row['no_of_uploads'] = $this->num_property->count_uploads();
```

> And in CodeIgniter, when you pass the array to view, its keys become
>   variable names.

For example.

```
<?php
$arr['user'] = 'Student';
$this->load->view('secondpage', $arr);
?>
```

In view, if you want to get `Student`, simply print

```
echo $user;
```

You need to print the variable `$no_of_uploads` instead of `$row['count']`

**Corrected code:**

```
<div class="rightside">
 <p><?php echo $_POST['location'];?>: <?php echo $no_of_uploads; ?> properties found</p>
</div>
```

Comment: its showing same error $no_of_uploads undefined in view

Comment: i already try that same as it is error coming $no_of_uploads undefine

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<div class = "rightside">
        <p><?php echo $_POST['location'];
    ?>: <?php echo $no_of_uploads; ?> properties found</p>
    </div>
```